# Big cat in heat for months?

Tags: reproduction

In this documentary about a lioness and a leopard the leopard is in heat for months.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGqmylkOuKw

Usually a big cat would be in heat for 5 days and then not in heat for 27 more days. Doesn't matter if it is a lion, tiger, cheetah, jaguar, or leopard, they have a very similar estrus cycle.

Why then is this leopard in heat for months until she finally becomes pregnant? The lioness is only in heat for 2 days because after 48 hours she becomes pregnant. In fact the lioness has 2 litters in the same period of time as the leopard has 1 litter.